# I get 'django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed' when attempting to load json data

Tags: python, django

I am trying to load some data from a json file into the website,but whenever i type required commands and want to save , i get the following error: (and by the way, only the first item of the json file gets showed in the website, and then i get the error)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)        
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\backend\website1\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

And Thats the code:

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Pleaaaaase help i have been stuck with this error for weeks

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView,CreateView,UpdateView,DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import     LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin
from django.http import HttpResponse
from Myapp.models import Post
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts':Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request,'home.html',context)

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','content']
    template_name = 'post_form.html'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author =  self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,UpdateView):
   model = Post
   fields = ['title','content']
   template_name = 'post_form.html'

   def form_valid(self,form):
    form.instance.author =  self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)

def test_func(self):
    post = self.get_object()
    if self.request.user == post.author:
        return True
    return False

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_confirm_delete.html'
    success_url = '/blog/'
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

def about(request):
   return render(request,'about.html',{'title':'about'})
```

Comment: if attempting to save an existing model instance that’s violating a foreign key constraint.

Comment: how can i implement the solution please

Comment: can you provide your views that how you are loading json data

Comment: done, but the json data is in a json file, i do it from the cmd

Comment: try by adding this `author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_constraint=False)` and after that makemigrations and migrate

Comment: where should i add it?, in the models.py file right?

Comment: it woooorked thanks!!!!